# Connecting to remote MySQL problems

Tags: mysql, windows-server-2008

Having a bit of a problem with mysql...

Mysql 5.1 on windows 2008 server iis7
Site on windows 2003 server iis6
[sorry but can't move to linux kids! ;)]

In the process of shifting a site to a new server so I have moved the database 1st and connected the site to the new database.  I tested the connection before moving but now the site is connecting to the new database I am having problems....

connecting via PDO the page hangs for an age before getting 'too many connections' error.  Monitoring the server I see MANY threads of: 'unathenticated user' from the ip address of the host the site runs on.

I also see a thread for the connection with the correct user name in my config file and I am a total loss as to what is going on.

Any help would be very much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 'unathenticated user' from the ip address of the host the site runs on

A stab in the dark, but this could be some script or process trying to connect to the database server with wrong or empty credentials.

Also, [here's](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=8945) a report from somebody who had similar problems - in that case, it was the DNS lookup that caused the problem.

> I had a similar situation on my setup where the database lived on a different host than
>   the webserver.  I found the "unauthenticated users" were connections from the webserver
>   that were hanging on DNS lookups.  Don't know if this is a mysql bug or a bug with my
>   firewall / other setup, but a couple of fixes I found were...
>
> 1) start mysql with --skip-name-resolve (you may have to change your mysql permission
>   tables to have the host's IP instead of hostname, including localhost)
>
> or 2) add the connecting host to your /etc/hosts file.

Comment: would that be 127.0.0.1 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

or

xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx localhost?

Comment: @Toon I don't understand what you mean?